# How to run android emulator in Docker on a linux host?

Tags: android, docker

I am not able to run the android emulator in Docker on a Linux (ArchLinux) host, despite having installed all packages and verified all permissions, it looks like the emulator is not able to find a `libGl` driver because I get this error (I imagine the Fontconfig warning is not relevant):

```
emulator @test
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
libGL error: pci id for fd 20: 8086:3ea0, driver (null)
libGL error: No driver found
libGL error: failed to load driver: (null)
```

These are the relevant steps I have performed to get HW acceleration working inside the container:

- installed `mesa-utils, libgl1-mesa-glx, libgl1-mesa-glx, libgl1-mesa-dri, mesa-utils-extra, xserver-xorg-video-all`;
- added the user to the `video` group
- map the volumes: `$HOME/.Xauthority:/home/node/.Xauthority:rw`, `/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw`, `/var/run/dbus:/var/run/dbus`
- start the container with `privileged: true`
- set the `DISPLAY` environment variable

I am able to run UI programs like Electron in docker containers with a similar configuration on the same machine but for some reason I am not able to run the android emulator.

`glxgears` works fine with this output:

```
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/node/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: pci id for fd 4: 8086:3ea0, driver (null)
libGL error: No driver found
libGL error: failed to load driver: (null)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/node/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/node/.drirc: No such file or directory.
7339 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1467.760 FPS
7656 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1531.003 FPS
.....
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to make it work by basically making sure the driver for my graphics card is installed inside the container. This is obviously very hardware specific but I:

- Updated the base docker image to use debian-buster (before I was using stretch)
- Installed `xserver-xorg-core` as explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/GraphicsCard#Intel)

This paired with all the steps outlined in my answer seems to work!

I have an integrated Intel Graphics card HD620.